# Computing rowwise means with dplyr, na.rm not working

Tags: r, dplyr, mean, na

I'm using the following code to compute the mean of several columns in my data:

```
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(avg=mean(Responsiveness:Translation, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I keep getting the error:

```
Error: NA/NaN argument
```

I know that some of my data has N/A values, but why doesn't na.rm=TRUE deal with them?

Comment: Please provide some example data and expected output.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would be helpful for that.

Comment: The error might be because you have a character 'N/A' value instead of real `NA`.  It would also change the column class from numeric to 'character' or 'factor' depending upon whether you used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` or not in the `read.csv`.  When you read the  dataset with `read.csv/read.table`, you can specify   `na.strings='N/A'`  so that it will be read as real NAs and the columns will be numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option using `rowMeans` within the `dplyr`.  We `select` the columns from 'Responsiveness' to (`:`) 'Translation', `mutate` the dataset to create the column 'avg' with `rowMeans`, specifying the `na.rm=TRUE` to remove the `NA` values, and `cbind` (`bind_cols`) with the remaining columns in the original dataset by subsetting the original dataset with columns that are not found in the `mutate`d  dataset i.e. `.`.  We can use `setdiff` to get the column names.

```
 library(dplyr)
 df %>% 
     select(Responsiveness:Translation) %>% 
     mutate(avg= rowMeans(., na.rm=TRUE)) %>% 
     bind_cols(df[setdiff(names(df), names(.))] , .)
```

---

But, doing `rowMeans` can be done without using any external package.  In `base R`, we `match` the columns 'Responsiveness', 'Translation' with the column names of  original dataset.  This gives the numeric index of those columns.  We can get the sequence (`:`) from 'start' (`i1[1]`), 'end' (`i1[2]`), and use `rowMeans` on the `subset` dataset.

```
 i1 <- match( c('Responsiveness', 'Translation'), names(df))
 df$avg <- rowMeans(df[i1[1]:i1[2]], na.rm=TRUE)
```

We can also remove some steps in the above `dplyr` code if we are using 'i1'

```
 df %>%
      mutate(avg= rowMeans(.[i1[1]:i1[2]], na.rm=TRUE))
```

NOTE: I am using `dplyr_0.4.1.9000` on `R 3.2.1`.  When there are no `NA` values, the OP's code is giving the same output as the `rowMeans`.  But, if there is an `NA` value, I get a different value i.e. for the 2nd row in the example, I get `3.5` instead of `3.66667`.  Though, I am not getting any error.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
df <- data.frame(V1=1:10, Responsiveness=1:10, V2= c(2, NA, 4:11), 
              V3=3:12, Translation=4:13)
```